# what is githubs api search parameter for to limit results to top X only?

Tags: javascript, api, github, parameters

This [link](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E1%20language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc&type=Repositories%27)

I am trying to get only top 5

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E1+language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc&type=Repositories%27
```

This is my array map loop.

```
       {languages.map(function (lang) {
    return (

      <li 
        className={(lang === props.selectedLanguage ? 'pure-menu-selected' : '') + ' pure-menu-item'}


        onClick={props.onSelect.bind(null, lang)}
        key={lang}>
          <a  className="pure-menu-link">{lang}</a>
      </li>
    )
  })}
```

Is it wrong to limit on my loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E1%20language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc&type=Repositories%27&page=1&per_page=5
```

Add "&page=1&per_page=5" to your querystring. You can find more details at Github's [API Docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination)